# Get only newly added and removed option from HTML select with multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-selectors

My question seem easy but I cannot figure it out.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KP5W2/)**

HTML:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
var choiceArr = [];
$('select').change(function () {
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    choiceArr.push(text);
    console.log(choiceArr);
});
```

So currently, if I choose **Volvo** and **Saab** the result will be:

```
["Volvo", "VolvoSaab"]
```

My expected result is:

```
["Volvo", "Saab"]
```

When I remove **Saab** from the selections, the result will be:

```
["Volvo", "VolvoSaab", "Volvo"]
```

My expected result is:

```
["Volvo"]
```

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Your fiddle link is broken... well, non-existant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XRbhu/5/)**

Try

```
var choiceArr = [];
$('select').change(function () {

    choiceArr = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    alert(choiceArr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<label id="result"></label>
```

Js

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var selValues = $.map($("#select1 option:selected"), function (temp) {
         return $(temp).text();
     });
     $("#result").text(selValues.join(", "));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/KP5W2/5/)**